# Change a value of Service after clicking on a notification

Tags: android, android-studio, service, notifications

Hy all

I want to make the following.

A service is runing on the background, when you Sake the phone a notification is shown, at the same time that other method starts runing with a "wait()",the think i want to do is, if you click the notification a boolean parameter of this service change his value in order to make diferent thinks depending if you click the notification or not.

Symplifyed code that I have:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{

    if (acc(event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2]) >15)
    {

        notificacioAccident();

    }
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) 
{

    synchronized (this) 
    {
        try {
            wait(waitTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }


    if(executar==true) 
    {
        //Do Something
    }
    else
    {
        //Do other think
    }
}

public void notificacioAccident() 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    intent.putExtra("executar",false); //Dosen't work
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.crash_2_1);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_app_icono));
    builder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.justAccident));
    builder.setContentText(this.getResources().getText(R.string.notificacio_1) + telefon);
    builder.setSubText(this.getResources().getText(R.string.notificacio_2));
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);//Prova
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```

As I've said, this is not all the code, only focus on how I can change the variable "executar" from true to false when I click on the notification that creates myService.

Thank you :D

Comment: Why `intent.putExtra("executar",false);` line `Dosen't work` ? are you getting value from Intent in onStartCommand method?

Comment: I don't know how I can catch then this value.

I don't make anythink onStartCommand() what i have to do?

Take in account that the variable that I want to change and notification() method are in the same class "I don't know it it matters or not"


I'm very new in Android, so I'm a bit lost

Comment: I find the final problema that i don't know how i have to solve it:

The problem is that I want to start the service when this code is runing:

    synchronized (this) 
    {
        try {
            wait(waitTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

And it's posible that this is not allowed, there is any method to do that?

I explain again, When a service is runing, create a notification and a wait, depending if in the wait time you click on the notification or not, diferent thinks happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found it:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); //Nou desde aqui
    if (extras != null) {
        executar=false;
    }                               //Fins aqui



@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{

if (acc(event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2]) >15)
{

    notificacioAccident();


    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            sendSMS();
        }
    }, waitTime);

}
}

private void sendSMS() 
{


    if(executar==true) 
    {
        //Do Something
    }
    else
    {
         //Do other think
    }
}

public void notificacioAccident() 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("executar",false); 
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.crash_2_1);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_app_icono));
    builder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.justAccident));
    builder.setContentText(this.getResources().getText(R.string.notificacio_1) + telefon);
    builder.setSubText(this.getResources().getText(R.string.notificacio_2));
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);//Prova
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
```